Zabbix\Postgre перенос на другой ПК
У меня есть Zabbix 5.4.12 (Ubuntu) и я хочу перелить все на Zabbix 6.0.34. (AltLinux)
Сделал бекап 6Gb через
pg_dump -h [ZABBIX SERVER] -U [ZABBIX DB USER] > /tmp/zabbix_dump.sql
На новом пытаюсь восстановить
sudo -u postgres psql zabbix < /tmp/zabbix_dump.sql
и получаю ошибки
неверная команда \N
ОШИБКА:  схема "_timescaledb_internal" не существует
...

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Полагаю в начале надо timescale поставить.
И вот тут почитайте
https://doc.scalingo.com/databases/postgresql/timescaledb#:~:text=an%20undesirable%20state.-,Dumping%20Your%20TimescaleDB%C2%AE,-The%20procedure%20to
